# Can Pinescript do this?

Tags: if-statement, pine-script, conditional-operator

thanks for any help. I'm new to coding. I was wondering if this is something Pinescript can achieve? The code below is not meant to be accurate at all. I'm including it to hopefully give you an idea of what I want to code. It would be a series of if/then statements piled on top of each other with the end result being a simple green or red background. Not sure if a ternary condition, function or if statement should be used.

A = if ( dataA > 0 )
green
else
red

B = if ( dataB > 0 )
green
else
red

C = if ( A = green and B = green )
bgcolor(color=color.green)

D = if ( A = red and B = red )
bgcolor(color=color.red)

Comment: Very possible..

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `color` variable and set its value with the ternary operator.

```
color c1 = dataA > 0 ? color.green : color.red
bgcolor(c1)
```

Or you can directly apply your condition in the `bgcolor()` function.

```
bgcolor(dataB > 0 ? color.green : color.red)
```